# Unterricht bei/mit, im/auf/am Stock

Tags: word-choice

Ich habe zwei Fragen zu Präpositionen:

1. Wenn Herr Jäger eine Veranstaltung führen würde, wie ist es richtig?

Wir haben einen Unterricht (eine Beratung, eine Besprechung)  mit/bei Herrn Jäger.

2. Ich bin auf dem/im/am ersten Stock (Etage, Geschoss)

Kommt es auf ein bestimmtes Wort, ob man "Etage", "Stock" oder "Geschoss" dazu benutzt, an?

Comment: Now these are three questions in one.... For the last one see: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/names-and-total-number-of-floors-in-buildings-what-is-correct and https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31441/the-difference-in-the-usage-of-die-etage-das-geschoss-and-der-stock

Answer (score 1):

1. "Wir haben einen Unterricht(eine Beratung, eine Baesprechung) mit/ bei Herren Jäger." 
   Das sind eigentlich 3 Fälle:

   ```
   Wir haben Unterricht mit/bei Herrn Jäger.
   Wir haben eine Besprechung mit Herrn Jäger.
   Wir haben ein Beratungsgespräch mit/bei Herrn Jäger.
   ```

"Unterricht/Gespräch mit Herrn Jäger" bedeutet, dass man von Herrn Jäger unterrichtet wird oder mit ihm ein Gespräch führt, aber nicht notwendigerweise an einem Ort, der mit ihm in Zusammenhang steht. "Unterricht/Gespräch bei Herrn Jäger" bedeutet, dass man von Herrn Jäger unterrichtet wird oder mit ihm ein Gespräch führt in seinem Büro, seinem Klassenzimmer etc.

2. "Ich bin auf dem/im/am ersten Stock( Etage, Geschoss)"

"auf dem" und "am" werden bestenfalls umgangssprachlich benutzt, sind aber beide nicht grammatikalisch korrekt. Nur "im 1. Stock/Geschoss bzw. in der 1. Etage" könnte man auch in einem schriftlichen Text benutzen.

1. "Wir haben einen Unterricht(eine Beratung, eine Baesprechung) mit/ bei Herren Jäger." 
   These are actually three cases:

   ```
   Wir haben Unterricht mit/bei Herrn Jäger.
   Wir haben eine Besprechung mit Herrn Jäger.
   Wir haben ein Beratungsgespräch mit/bei Herrn Jäger.
   ```

"Unterricht/Gespräch mit Herrn Jäger" means that you get taught by/talk to Mr. Jäger, but not necessarily at a location related to him. "Unterricht/Gespräch bei Herrn Jäger" means that you get taught by/talk to Mr. Jäger at his school/office etc.

2. "Ich bin auf dem/im/am ersten Stock( Etage, Geschoss)"

"auf dem" and "am" are at best used colloqially but not grammatically correct. Only "im 1. Stock/Geschoss bzw. in der 1. Etage" could be used in a written text.

Answer (score 1):

> Wir haben Unterricht mit Herrn Jäger.
>
> Wir haben Unterricht bei Herrn Jäger.

Beides ist korrekt. Mit dem Wort "mit" gehst du implizit davon aus, dass Herr Jäger dabei ist. "bei Heern Jäger" könnte auch bedeuten, dass etwas an seinem Haus stattfindet, er aber nicht dabei ist.

> Ich bin auf dem ersten Stock.

Das ist korrekt, wird aber eher selten verwendet.

> Ich bin im ersten Stock.

Das ist korrekt und das würde ich auch so verwenden.

> Ich bin am ersten Stock

Das wäre falsch.

> Ich bin auf der ersten Etage.

Das ist korrekt, ich würde aber eher "in" statt "auf" sagen.

> Ich bin in der ersten Etage.

Das ist korrekt.

> Ich bin an der ersten Etage

Das ist komplett falsch.

> Ich bin auf dem ersten Geschoss.

Das ist falsch.

> Ich bin im ersten Geschoss.

Das ist korrekt.

> Ich bin am ersten Geschoss

Das würde man so nicht sagen.